# Build Sequence for multiple projects of the same solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have one straight forward question. Suppose i have a projectA and now i have to add projectB to the solution of projectA. Is there a way to build ProjectA first and after the execution of that is complete can we build projectB and execute..? Consider that both these projects dont have to anything in common.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Right-click the solution node on your Solution Explorer, and select "Project Build Order".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the `Solution` node in the Solution Explorer, then `Project Build Order...`.

Using the `Dependencies` tab you can set `ProjectA` as a dependency of `ProjectB` - this would cause `ProjectA` to build before `ProjectB`.